# Verification of Proof for "Differentiability implies Continuity" based on Epsilon-Delta

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

We are given that function $\mathbb{f}$ is differentiable at $\mathbb x$. We have to show that it is also continuous at $\mathbb x$.

Now, according to definition of differentiability,

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ such that

$$|t-x| < \delta \implies \left|\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x} - L\right| < \epsilon$$

Now, $|x - y| \ge |x| - |y|$.

$$\therefore \left|\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}\right|  - |L|< \epsilon$$

$$\therefore |f(t) - f(x)| < |t-x| * (\epsilon + |L|) < \delta*(\epsilon+|L|)$$

Now take $\delta' = \frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon + |L|}$

So,
$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta' > 0$ such that,
$$|f(t) - f(x)| < \delta'*(\epsilon + |L|)$$
$$\therefore |f(t) - f(x)| < \left(\frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon + |L|}\right) * (\epsilon + |L|)$$
$$\therefore |f(t) - f(x)| < \epsilon$$

So, we have proved that
$$\lim_{t\to x} f(t) = f(x)$$

Hence, function is continuous at x.
Is this proof valid ?
Thanks.

Comment: Not to be a jerk, but without looking at your proof in detail I'd suggest this shorter version. We know that $|\frac{f(t) - f(x)}{t - x} - L| < \epsilon$ for $0 < |t - x| < \delta$, so $|f(t) - f(x) - L(t - x)| < \epsilon|t-x| < \epsilon \cdot \delta$. Then using $|a| - |b| \le |a-b|$, $|f(t) - f(x)| \le (|L| + \epsilon)|t - x| < (|L| + \epsilon)\delta.$ This can be made small by choosing $\delta$ sufficiently small.

Comment: Yes. That's what I have done. Means this is right ?

Comment: @MeetR Yes, this is right.